# Excel VBA - loop to place multiple row values into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and trying to create a loop that will take an array of client names (obtained from splitting the caption of Userform label RepList1), return the worksheet row in which each name is found, and then place those row values into their own array for further usage.

Seems simple, but it's giving me all kinds of headaches - Subscript out of range, Type mismatch, etc. With the current version below, it's "91: Object variable or With block variable not set" when it tries to fill ShowRow.

Any ideas?

```
Sub CreateRep_Click()

Dim reportlist() As String
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim ShowRow() As Long
Dim a As Long

reportlist = Split(RepList1.Caption, Chr(10))

Sheet1.Activate
For a = 1 To UBound(reportlist)
    Set FindRow = Sheet1.Columns("A").Find(what:=reportlist(a - 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    ShowRow(a - 1) = FindRow.Row
Next a

'code using ShowRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You have not set a size for the array `ShowRow`  after the split line put `Redim ShowRow(0 to ubound(reportlist))`

Comment: Thank you, but same result. :(

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: ShowRow(a - 1) = FindRow.Row

Comment: are you sure that `FindRow` actually is set? perhaps the value was not found. In which case you may need to error trap.

Comment: I intend ShowRow to store multiple row values, so I do need it to be an array. Not experienced with error trapping...?

Comment: Yes. I get what you intend. If you `debug.print FindRow.Address` what shows up in the immediate window? Or more specifically, are you **absolutely sure** that all the values in `reportlist` will always be found on in `Sheet1.Columns("A")`?

Comment: reportlist is being populated from Sheet1.Columns("A") in the first place, so I'm reasonably sure. I threw in a MsgBox reportlist(0) before the loop to see if it found what it was supposed to, and it did. debug.print FindRow.Address gives me the same error.

Comment: try `worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A")...` in place of `Sheet1.Columns("A")...`

Comment: .columns("A") works fine, but the problem is that `FindRow` is not being set because it can't find the value in `reportlist(0)` in column A as you have written the find statement. `Msgbox reportlist(0)` will not tell you that it found it in column A, it just gives the value of reportlist(0). Can you post a screenshot of the data and where you are pulling the reportlist array from? Also, make sure there are no extra spaces or anything loaded into the `reportlist array` as the `xlWhole` argument you set will not work if there are extra (perhaps unseen) characters.

Comment: http://imgur.com/ikqz1rc

Comment: The combobox is populated from Column A when the userform is initialized, and the "Add" button builds the list in that label caption. The code I've given you is from the Create Report button sub.

Comment: reportlist is zero-based (see [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528.aspx) help) so running `For a = 1 To UBound(reportlist)` will miss out reportlist(0)

Comment: I offset my array references within the loop to compensate for that. I also tried For a = 0 To (UBound(reportlist)-1) and still get that error.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem. It's the Chr(10) that .Find doesn't like. If I use a period, comma, or any other delimiter to connect and then split the original list of values by, .Find works with them just fine. But not Chr(10). Any ideas on why this might be, or how to get around it?